# Using XSLT is it possible to compare two xml?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

To find the differences between two xml files, is it possible to use XSLT, if yes can you share a small example xslt ??   Note the xslt should be able to take any two xml files it should not assume any specific tree structure

Answer (score 2):

Before you start coding this in XSLT or any other language, you need to write a specification of what you want the program to do. This is a complex requirement that can't be defined in three lines. There's at least one company - DeltaXML - that does this for a living.

The first challenge is to define what it means for two files to be the same. (You could take the specification of fn:deep-equal as a starting point). Once you've done that, the much harder problem is to define what output you want to produce when the files are different. To take one very simple example, what output would you want for the files:

(a)

```
<a><b/><c/></a>
```

(b)

```
<a><c/><b/></a>
```

Comment: in this example there is no difference

Comment: which sort of proves the point: you can't specify this one example at a time, you need to write the general rules.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with XSLT 2.0 you can use the `deep-equal` https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-deep-equal function to compare two sequences in general or two document nodes if you need to e.g. `deep-equal(doc('file1.xml'), doc('file2.xml'))` with return true if the two files are considered equal as defined in the linked spec.

As for finding "the differences", you have not even explained what kind of result you are looking for. Saxon 9 in the commercial editions has `saxon:deep-equal` which according to http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/deep-equal.html allows you to set the `?` flag and an error listener

> Explain reason for a non-match. If the result is not-equal, a warning
>   message explaining the reason will be sent to the ErrorListener. (In
>   general, a sequence of warning messages will be sent, starting with
>   the lowest-level difference and moving up the tree)

But that is not something standardized.